# Google Chrome: Alphablending result differs when using CSS transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

Testcase:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #toMove {
            transition: transform 1s;
            width: 350px; height: 350px; background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0,0.3);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            let x = e.clientX;
            document.getElementById("toMove").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, 0px)";
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="toMove"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When the square is moving, the alphablended result is rgb(222, 255, 192).
When it is stationary, the alphablended result is rgb(204, 255, 181).

Chrome version: 102.0.5005.115
Works fine in Firefox 101.0.1.
OS: Windows 10

Is this a Chrome bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome fixes the bug. So it's a Chrome bug, I suppose.